# What is the difference between read and readline in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-c++

What is the difference between `read()` and `readline()` in C#?

Maybe we don't use it but in my academy the only difference is that one has "line" and the other don't have...
In c++, there is "cin" and it has "endl" to add line.
Can somebody tell me the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean `TextReader.Read` and `TextReader.ReadLine`?

One overload of `TextReader.Read` reads characters into a buffer (a `char[]`), and you can specify how many characters you want it to read (as a maximum). Another reads a single character, returning an `int` which will be -1 if you've reached the end of the reader.

`TextReader.ReadLine` reads a whole line as a `string`, which doesn't include the line terminator.

As far as I'm aware, `endl` is more commonly used in conjunction with `cout` in C++:

```
cout << "Here's a line" << endl;
```

In .NET you'd use

```
writer.WriteLine("Here's a line")
```

to accomplish the same thing (for an appropriate `TextWriter`; alternatively use `Console.WriteLine` for the console).

EDIT: `Console.ReadLine` reads a line of text, whereas `Console.Read` reads a single character (it's like the parameterless overload of `TextWriter.Read`).

`Console.ReadLine()` is basically the same as `Console.In.ReadLine()` and `Console.Read()` is basically the same as `Console.In.Read()`.

EDIT: In answer to your comment to the other answer, you can't do:

```
int x = Console.ReadLine();
```

because the return type of `Console.ReadLine()` is a string, and there's no conversion from `string` to `int`. You *can* do

```
int x = Console.Read();
```

because `Console.Read()` returns an `int`. (Again, it's the Unicode code point or -1 for "end of data".)

EDIT: If you want to read an integer from the keyboard, i.e. the user types in "15" and you want to retrieve that as an integer, you should use something like:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
int value;
if (int.TryParse(line, out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully parsed value: {0}", value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number - try again!");
}
```

Comment: sorry but i was mean "Console.ReadLine()" and "Console.Read()"

Comment: ok, but what is your recommendation words about read integer from keyboard : use read or readline and do convert ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Console.Read and Console.ReadLine, the difference is that Read only returns a single character, while ReadLine returns the entire input line.  Its important to note that in both cases, the API call won't return until the user presses ENTER to submit the text to the program.  So if you type "abc" but don't press ENTER, both Read and ReadLine will block until you do.

Comment: ok , but why this :
            int x;

            x = Console.Read();   //ok
            x = Console.ReadLine();   /*Error canot convert from string to integer*/

and in c++ ,i 'm not need to do convert to get the input data to integer using cin.on the other hand ,c# if you use Console.ReadLine() you must do convert..?(up)

Comment: Console.ReadLine() returns a string, not an int.